# Find a free TCP port with boost ASIO

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, distributed-computing

I have a C++ main programme which calls to two sub-processes. The two sub-process are connected throught the TCP port assigned by the main programme.

I see the useusal case to find a free port is that the programme will try to bind in a given port and if is return "failed", give a port++ and try again.

While for my case, I need to decide in my main programme that which port number shall be passed to those two sub-processes.

So is there an easy way to check if a port can be used without trying to bind to it?

Like

```
port = 1234
while(port < 1299)
  if(port is bindable) 
    call to subprocesses
    break;
  else
    port++
```

Comment: Edge case you might face: you check that port is free and pass it but before the sub-process start up and bind to it some other process steals it.

Answer (score 3):

The *correct* way to find a free port is to let the OS choose an available port for you.  Create a socket and bind it to port 0, then query the socket to find out which port was actually bound. Every major OS supports that feature.  What the particular syntax is for accomplishing that in Boost ASIO, I have no clue.

Then you have to address the issue of each port actually being in use once it is bound, so you would have to either:

1. make the main program create and bind 2 sockets and then pass the existing sockets to the sub-processes for use.
2. make the sub-processes create and bind their own local sockets with the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option enabled so they can bind to the same ports that the main program bound to (even if the main program closed its bound sockets before starting the sub-processes).
3. make the sub-processes obtain their own ports (by binding to port 0) and then report the actual port numbers back to the main program, which can then pass them around between the sub-processes as needed.

Answer (score 1):

> I see the usual case to find a free port is that the programme will try to bind in a given port and if is return "failed", give a port++ and try again.

No it isn't. I don't know where you saw that, but the usual and correct case is to specify port zero and let the operating system do it, then use `getsockname()` to discover what port the OS allocated.